# Firestore index not working but it´s already created

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the clients that belong to a specific center and order them by descending date but it seems that my index is not working correctly.

This are my index in Firestore

[image: Firestore index]

And here my code:

```
db.collection("clientes")
    .where("idCentro", "==", idCentro)
    .orderBy("createAt", "desc")
```

I also tested this:

```
 db.collection("clientes")
    .where("idCentro", "==", idCentro)
    .orderBy("createAt", "desc")
    .orderBy("nombre", "asc")
```

The error: **no matching index found.**

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3583